# Vagrant up error, requires a second vagrant up

Tags: vagrant

**Problem:** `vagrant up` fails the first time with the error below, and `vagrant up` again starts the vagrant box successfully. I am running vagrant on Windows 7 and the base box is Ubuntu 12.04 from [here](http://www.vagrantbox.es/)

Whats causing the error, and how can it be fixed?

**Output (with VAGRANT_LOG=DEBUG)**

```
C:/vagrant/vagrant/bin//../embedded/bin/vagrant:19:in `load'
C:/vagrant/vagrant/bin//../embedded/bin/vagrant:19:in `<main>'
 INFO interface: error: There was an error executing the following command with VBoxManage:

["modifyvm", "1a08aaf5-f8b5-4e1e-a773-a91fdec7a6b6", "--name", "test_1349794733"]

For more information on the failure, enable detailed logging with VAGRANT_LOG.
There was an error executing the following command with VBoxManage:

["modifyvm", "1a08aaf5-f8b5-4e1e-a773-a91fdec7a6b6", "--name", "test_1349794733"]

For more information on the failure, enable detailed logging with VAGRANT_LOG.
```

*Why is it asking me to enable detailed logging? Isn't `VAGRANT_LOG=DEBUG` the highest level?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the information on how to enable detailed logging appears whether or not you enabled it. I wouldn't worry too much about it.

You can try running the command yourself to see if you can get anymore information. Should be something like

```
VBoxManage modifyvm 1a08aaf5-f8b5-4e1e-a773-a91fdec7a6b6 --name test_1349794733
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this on windows and got `'VBoxManage' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Are you sure you're either (a) in the same directory as `VBoxManage.exe` or (b) that it's in your PATH? The easiest thing is to change to the directory where VBoxManage is installed and try it again. See: http://serverfault.com/a/365435/36968

Comment: Thanks, I tried `>c:\"Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" modifyvm 1a08aaf5-f8b5-4e1e-a773-a91fdec7a6b6 --name test_1349794733` and there is no errors or output. I did this after the first `vagrant up` quit with the `modifyvm` error.

Comment: Are there any messages (error message, or just **plain output**) above what you've shown in your question?

Comment: Oh there are more error messages, please take a look at this pastebin http://paste.laravel.com/7ro

Comment: Permissions issue? And do you actually have a user account named "x"? The error starting on line 15 indicates that the directory could not be renamed. Any idea why?

Comment: Yes the windows 7 user i am using is named 'x'. Hmmm permissions issue under Windows? I have already disabled User Account Controls (UAC). I tried running `cmd` as Administrator but I get the same error.

Comment: Well, I realize my answer hasn't actually provided many answers, but I would start with that rename issue and try to track that down, since it's the first error. Also, maybe try something simple like reinstalling VirtualBox and Vagrant and/or making sure all the versions match up with the latest stuff. Good luck.

Comment: I'm also seeing this issue.  It almost seems like a timing issue where it's trying to rename too soon after something was written and windows hasn't quite released the resource yet.  Running the VBoxManage rename command from the command line executes fine.  Have you found a solution yet?